# eCommerce/Fee Box tabs out of place

Tags: jquery, html, bigcommerce

I can't figure out why this is not working on my site.  This is supposed to create a box with text and fees information.  The fees are grabbed from custom product fields.  For some reason, the tabs are missing and the tab content is layed out at the bottom of the page.  Weird.

Here is a link to my store: http://inflatableboats.net/ab-alumina-alx-15-alx-with-yamaha-f50lb-four-stroke/

Here is the css for the box:

```
#shippingInfo {margin: 20px auto 20px;padding: 10px;border: 1px dashed #ccc;background: #eee;}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
%%Panel.HTMLHead%%
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="Container">
    %%Panel.Header%%

    <div id="Wrapper">
        %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%
        <div class="Left" id="LayoutColumn1">
            %%Panel.SideCategoryList%%
            %%Panel.SideNewProducts%%
            %%Panel.SideNewsletterBox%%
            %%Panel.SideLiveChatServices%%
        </div>
        <div class="Content" id="LayoutColumn2">
            %%Panel.ProductBreadcrumb%%
            %%Panel.ProductDetails%%
            %%Panel.ProductTabs%%
            %%Panel.ProductDescription%%
            %%Panel.ProductVideos%%
            %%Panel.ProductWarranty%%
            %%Panel.ProductOtherDetails%%
            %%Panel.SimilarProductsByTag%%
            %%Panel.ProductByCategory%%
            %%Panel.ProductVendorsOtherProducts%%
            %%Panel.SimilarProductsByCustomerViews%%
        </div>
        <div class="Right" id="LayoutColumn3">
            %%Panel.SideCurrencySelector%%
            %%Panel.SideProductAddToWishList%%
            %%Panel.SideProductRelated%%
            %%Panel.SideProductRecentlyViewed%%
        </div>
        <br class="Clear" />
    </div>
    %%Panel.Footer%%
</div>
<!-- productotherdetailsinformation -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var otherDetails = $('#ProductTabs #ProductOtherDetails_Tab');
            if ( otherDetails .length){
                $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow').each(function() {
                  var shipsTruck = $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .Value').html();
                  if ("shipsTruck:contains('truck')") {
                      var checkEstimate = 'true';
                    $('.productAddToCartRight').append('<p style="margin-left:140px;"><strong><em>This product ships by truck only. <a href="#shippingInfo">See shipping notes</a> below for more information.</em></strong></p>');
                    $('.ProductDescription, .ProductOtherDetails').append('<div id="shippingInfo">' <p><strong>NOTE:</strong>THIS PRODUCT CANNOT SHIP STANDARD GROUND. It must be shipped via a boat hauler, hand delivered by company personnel, or through a professional freight company and requires special handling and prepping to ship. Please e-mail <a href="mailto:ibs@inflatableboats.net">ibs@inflatableboats.net</a> for a valid shipping and handling cost estimate.</p>
    <p><strong>PLEASE NOTE:</strong></p>
    <p>The price displayed above is the base selling price for the boat and Motor ONLY.</p>
    <p class="pdifee"><strong>PDI (Dealer Prep and Testing) includes the following: Validates all warranties, fill fluids in outboard, complete system check, install AGM Marine battery, electrical check, test run, sea trial:</strong></p>
    <p class="dffee"><strong>Destination Fee (Freight in to Inflatable Boat Specialists Warehouse): </strong></p></div>');
                    return false;
                  }
                });
 for(var index = 0; index < $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow').length; index++){
                    var thisOther = $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow .Label').eq(index).html();                    
                    if (thisOther == 'PDI') {
                        var estimateCost = $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow .Value').eq(index).html();
                        if (estimateCost) {
                            $('.pdifee').append(estimateCost);
                        } else {
                            $('.pdifee').append('call');
                        }
                    }
                }
for(var index = 0; index < $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow').length; index++){
                    var thisOther = $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow .Label').eq(index).html();                    
                    if (thisOther == 'DF') {
                        var estimateCost = $('#ProductOtherDetails .ProductDetailsGrid .DetailRow .Value').eq(index).html();
                        if (estimateCost) {
                            $('.dffee').append(estimateCost);
                        } else {
                            $('.dffee').append('call');
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }


        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem...

Comment: FYI, the CSS is not located on this page.  I just posted it so people would understand what I am trying to accomplish.  It is located on a separate style sheet.

Comment: Please be very specific about what's wrong. We don't know your project like you do.

Comment: If you look at my site, you will notice there is no box made with CSS.  Also, the "Other Details", "Find Similar Products" at the bottom of the page are supposed to be in tabs.

Comment: Why are my product tabs missing, but the content from them is being shown under the product description?

Answer (score 2):

The first glaring thing I see is that you're attempting to include a folder via your script tag instead of an actual JS file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://inflatableboats.net/js/"></script>
```

In addition, given the code you pasted you will get an error when the following line gets processed:

```
if ( otherDetails .length){
```

It should read:

```
if ( otherDetails.length){
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I am confused.  I am linking to the CDN jQuery on Google, so I don't understand "attempting to include a folder..."  I fixed the otherDetails.length.  Still not working as intended.

Comment: No one is checking this anymore.  This is not solved.  Why are my product tabs missing, but the content from them is being shown under the product description?

Comment: Look in the <head> area of your page and you'll see the script tag I'm talking about. If you open your browser's console you'll see a slew of JS errors. Nothing is going to work properly until you correct those errors.

Comment: Right below <body>, I replaced the <script> see above with this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_AppPath%%/javascript/jquery/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_AppPath%%/javascript/product.functions.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="%%GLOBAL_AppPath%%/javascript/product.js?%%GLOBAL_JSCacheToken%%"></script>

Replacing these fixed the tabs on my page.  Now to just get the Fee Box working as intended.

Comment: Although, my tabs are blank.  The information was showing on the page, but once they are in tabs it disappears.  God it is hard being a beginner.  So many pieces of the puzzle missing.

Comment: Everyone starts at the same place. When it comes to JS there's just so many variables. I would suggest always going back to the console and to slow down. So much more can be understood when you aren't in a rush, you know?